# Why is my device samsung SM-G350 incompatible with ?app

Tags: android, device-compatibility

I have uploaded my app in play store but my app is incompatible with my device. Someone please explain why?

My manifest file is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.mechanicapp.mechanicapp"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.2" >
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="4"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Please post more of your manifest, particularly any `<uses-feature>`, `<supports-screens>`, or `<compatible-screens>` elements that you may have.

Comment: I didnt use any of those. after this my <application> tag starts

Comment: Did you enable all countries in the "Pricing and distribution" page in developer console? Manifest seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes I enabled it for all countries. The app is free but still I have the problem. My manifest has nothing more than what I posted here.

Comment: Google play gives same incompatible message even for a simple HelloWorld app